# Best way to log nodejs application to kafka topic

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, logstash, winston

Currently my app uses winston for logging to console and to logstash, but I have need to send logs to kafka and then stream them to spark and write data to cassandra. I came across several different approaches to solve this:

1. One is to log to a file and then to use filebeats to output log to kafka
2. Second is to output data from logstash
3. there are some other solutions including using kafka-logger package (to send data directly from winston to kafka), but I don't know how safe would it be, since git repo hasn't been updated in 2yrs.

I hope that I provided enough informations about problem, if not so, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Be cause I'm using spark for some transformations and clustering.

Answer (score 2):

There are native JS clients available, such as https://kafka.js.org/

In general you're going to have a happier time sending events directly to Kafka without involving flat files. It's just more moving pieces to go wrong (and to make life harder if you want to scale out or move execution to another node).

BTW for getting data to Cassandra from Kafka just use [Kafka Connect](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-cassandra) :)

Comment: For kafka I'm already using kafka-node package. I'll consider writing some wrapper around kafka and winston logger to publish logs to kafka when writing them on console. Anyways thanks for the answer !